# Masonry and dynamic tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry

I have this page that contains dynamic tabs. The content inside the tabs changes depending on the tab the user picks. I want to get that content to be laid out with Masonry so that it looks nice.

Here's the problem: When the user switches tabs the content collapses. Like this:
[image]

If the user plays around with the window size it responds and lays out correctly. Like this:
[image]

Now I am pretty sure I know what the issue is here. I am using masonry on HTML and not jquery:
`<div class="row" data-masonry='{ "columnWidth": ".news-box", "itemSelector": ".news-box" }'>`

So I think the issue is that masonry on HTML doesn't work that well if the content isn't loaded (the images, in this case). I have looked around for JQuery approaches to solve this and my problem is that I can't get JQuery to work for some reason. This site is on ASP.NET and I can't get masonry on JQuery going, which is why I am stuck with HTML.

This is what I have tried, without any success, with JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('.row').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.news-box',
        columnWidth: '.news-box'
    });
</script>
```

I know that piece of code doesn't wait for the images to load. My point is that I don't get any results, even erroneous with that code.

Is there any way I can solve this on HTML? Make it so that when a user switches tabs the contents lay out perfectly to begin with?

**Edit**: I got this working with vanilla JS

```
var msnry = new Masonry('.row', {
    columnWidth: '.news-box',
    itemSelector: '.news-box'
});
```

Maybe I can get an event handler in here? Tips?

**Example code that replicates problem**

```
<!--TABS-->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>

<!--TAB CONTENT-->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <!--DUMMY CONTENT FOR MAIN TAB-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <!--DUMMY CONTENT FOR SECONDARY TAB-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
                <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual solution, based on your provided code:

```js
var updateMasonry = function(){
  $('.tab-pane.active').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.well',
  })
}

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', updateMasonry);
$(window).on('resize load', updateMasonry)
```

```js
var updateMasonry = function(){
  $('.tab-pane.active').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.well',
  })
}

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', updateMasonry);
$(window).on('resize load', updateMasonry)
```

```css
/* you don't need this css */
@media (min-width: 700px) {
.container {margin-top: 80px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--TAB CONTENT-->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <!--DUMMY CONTENT FOR MAIN TAB-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <!--DUMMY CONTENT FOR SECONDARY TAB-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 well well-sm">
          <img src="https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/css-stack-overflow-animated-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h4>title title title title title title title</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--TABS-->
```

---

**Initial answer**, unfolded...

The `<script>` tag you posted will be run when it is met. This means it will be executed when:

- your `DOM` object has not yet been fully constructed
- your images haven't loaded (because DOM building happens much faster than loading images).

That's why you need to push the execution of your code on the `window.load` event, which happens when all assets finished loading:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var msnry = new Masonry('.row', {
    columnWidth: '.news-box',
    itemSelector: '.news-box'
  });
};
```

<del>Also, I'm not entirely sure pasing a selector to `columnWidth` param is valid. I think it can only take width-like values (you can go `25%` to avoid pixels). My guess is it's currently ignored. It also doesn't make much sense, since you're giving it the `width` of the elements you're resizing...</del>

---

**Further details**.
From comments, it results you're trying to apply `.masonry()` to content placed in inactive tabs. In most tabs mechanisms, this means the tab container has `display:none`, which makes it not rendered and its `width` will return 0. Because `masonry()` uses the container's width to calculate the columns, and place the items, it does work, but all the columns have 0 width. Here's what you probably want to do.

**Step 1.** Place your masonry init method inside a function, so you can call it when you need it:

```
 var massonryInit = function() {
    var msnry  = new Masonry('.row', {
    columnWidth: '.news-box',
    itemSelector: '.news-box'
 });
```

**Step 2.** Look in the documentation of whatever tabs you are using for a callback method run on tab contents after the tab is shown. If they were Bootstrap tabs we would be talking about `shown.bs.tab` event, but I know you're not using Bootstrap because you're not using `jQuery`.

On that method you'll need to call your newly declared `massonryInit()` function:

```
var yourTab = document.querySelector('yourTabSelectorHere');
yourTab.addEventListener("yourTabWasRenderedEvent", masonryInit);
```

Note the above method will only work on a single, specific tab, returned by `yourTabselectorHere`. If that selector matches more than one element, the event will only be added to first match. To add it to all, you need `.querySelectorAll()` instead of `.querySelector()` and you'll need to run a javascript `for` on that collection and add the event to each.

By default, JavaScript is pretty verbose. That's why `jQuery` is so popular. It reduces writing common methods and tasks to much shorter syntax. All the above, using jQuery would be:

```
var masonryInit = function(){
  $('.row').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.news-box',
  });
}
$('yourTabSelectorHere').on('yourTabWasRenderedEvent', masonryInit);
```

... and it would work on multiple tabs. No `for` loop needed. It would be internally applied by `jQuery`.

Adding to the great explanation above, this article is a great read:
https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/

Comment: I understand. This is JQuery and I can't get JQuery going on my site, any way to do this with vanilla JS?

Comment: @CStruggle, updated for use without jQuery. It wasn't clear to me you're not using `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it does work but doesn't solve my problem. My site has tabs and if the tab that contains the content I want to apply masonry to isn't the tab that loads first, but one that the user must switch to then your solution doesn't apply. Check it out here if you can: http://tdigest.azurewebsites.net/Home/Contact
Only the main tab gets masonry, and the "Menu 1" tab doesn't

Comment: You're missing a principle here. `.masonry()` will take the width of the parent to calculate columns and, subsequently, to position each element in its position. If your parent is a tab container with `display:none` it doesn't have much of a `width`, does it? So you're applying masonry on content that has no size. ***You need to call `masonry()` on the content of your tab, after the tab was rendered***. Whatever tabs you are using, I'm pretty sure they have a callback method for when a tab was painted. That's when you need to call `masonry()`.

Comment: Understood. How would I approach calling masonry after the tab was rendered? Onload event?

Comment: @CStruggle I appreciate your struggle and effort into trying not to use `jQuery` but from our discussion my opinion is you've taken this decision a tad too soon. You need to have a better understanding of what happens technically in a web page, how content is loaded, how everything works, etc... Please don't get me wrong. I appreciate it. You'll learn faster/more on the path you chose, but it will be harder for a while and you'll be less productive. Updated my answer. Cheers!

Comment: I understand. This is the first site I have ever made and whenever anyone learns anything new there's always gaps to fill. I actively try to learn more of what I haven't experienced yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using Bootstrap tabs. I 100% understand JQuery is *much* better than plain JavaScript it's just that I can't get it working on my site and I am still trying to figure out why. Anything in JQuery just doesn't work. I'll solve it eventually I just want to clarify I am not being stubborn here, just working with what I have and solving issues as I go.

Comment: Than, just to clarify, `Bootstrap.js` does not work without `jQuery`. So, whether you know it or not, jQuery is loaded in your page, or the tabs wouldn't work. Please provide a [mcve] of your example and I'll make it work.

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is up in the end of original question. I boiled it down to the very basics.

Comment: [mcve] means: live. You have a snippet widget here `<>` button that enables you to put each code in its place, add dependencies and reproduce the problem here. This is for future reference, I'll place it in a snippet and update the answer with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: @CStruggle updated. Since Bootstrap tabs won't work without jquery, I also used jquery.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although copying and pasting this on Visual Studio doesn't work I will now make sure I correct any issues on my end

Comment: As you can see it works here, but I used selectors for whatever was posted here. There's no `.news-box` in your posted snippet, so i used `.well`.

Comment: Oh yes I see that. I am testing this on VS with exactly the same code I gave you. I have to admit I am pretty frustrated I can't get something this simple going but there's surely a solution.

Comment: Make a jsFiddle with what you have, not generic example and I'll have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146336/discussion-between-cstruggle-and-andrei-gheorghiu).

Answer (score 1):

The best - simple solution i find is to **destroy and initialized**:

Demo (Tabby.js & Masonry): https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/KOLdBO?editors=1111

> Removes the Masonry functionality completely. destroy will return the
>   element back to its pre-initialized state.

```
  $grid.masonry("destroy");
  $grid.masonry(masonryOptions);
```

**Flow (Use this with your tabs code): **Click on `tabX` show `contectX` - destroy `gridX` than reload `gridX` - **works like magic** without any complex tricks (Like timeout or resize) :)

**The idea comes from official docs (`Toggle Masonry`):**

`Masonry - destroy`

- Codepen: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jPyoRE
- Docs: https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#destroy

**Why not using "layout" (reload)?**

Because this idea will work only if you change the grid (Append/prepended item, change elements size and so on).

```
  // trigger layout after item size changes
  $grid.masonry('layout');
```

**Example** (toggle class and update layout):
https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout-masonry